# How should I translate "驚破という場合に望みては"?

Tags: classical-japanese, interjections

I am reading [外科室](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000050/files/360_19397.html). At some point, there is this sentence:

> さてはいかなる医学士も、[驚破]{すわ}という場合に望みては、さすがに懸念のなからんやと、予は同情を表したりき。

[驚破]{すわ}という場合 is a reference to an earlier passage,

> 手術台なる伯爵夫人は、純潔なる白衣を絡いて、死骸のごとく横たわれる、顔の色あくまで白く、鼻高く、頤細りて手足は綾羅にだも堪えざるべし。脣の色少しく褪せたるに、玉のごとき前歯かすかに見え、眼は固く閉ざしたるが、眉は思いなしか顰みて見られつ。わずかに束ねたる頭髪は、ふさふさと枕に乱れて、台の上にこぼれたり。

Clearly it is about the surprise of the doctor who will have to deal with such a patient. However, I can't see how to translate 驚破という場合に望みては with something different than *when dealing with such a case*, hiding the difficulty in *such*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doctor is not surprised. すわ in this context is an old interjection used like いざ, さあ, そら, etc. (I didn't know it has the kanji 驚破. Looks like it's an ateji, and [泉鏡花 liked it](https://furigana.info/w/%E9%A9%9A%E7%A0%B4:%E3%81%99%E3%82%8F).) See the second definition from 大辞林 第三版:

> #### すわ
>
> （ 感 ）
>   ① 突然の出来事などに驚いて発する語。 「 －一大事」
>   ② 他人の注意を喚起する語。 「 －見給へとて、古狸をなげ出いだしたりけり／著聞 17」

This 望む means "to face (a situation)", and is usually written as 臨む now.

So, 驚破という場合に望みては means いざという場合に臨んでは or さあ(これから手術本番だ)という場面に直面したら in modern Japanese.

Comment: I only knew the first definition of すわ. It, now, make much more sense and it is indeed easier to render in English. Thank you.